# Change font in XML using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSLT. I'm trying to change the font size of a specific text in XML file using XSLT. For eg- I have the CDCatalog.xml file with following data.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcat.xsl"?>

<catalog>
 <cd>
  <title>Empire Burlesque</title> 
  <artist><SmallText>Bob Dylan</SmallText><LineBreak/>*</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>Columbia</company> 
  <price>10.90</price> 
  <year>1985</year> 
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

and the cdCat.XSL file is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:include href="cdCatalog.xsl" /> <!-- I added this -->
<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2> 
 <table border="1">
 <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
  <th align="left">Title</th> 
  <th align="left">Artist</th> 
  </tr>
 <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
 <tr>
 <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="title" /> 
  </td>
 <td>
 <xsl:value-of select="artist" /> 
  </td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>

  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I added a new xsl file cdCatalog.XSL file with following details-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="LineBreak">
    <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Superscript">
    <sup>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </sup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SmallText">
    <font size="1">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </font>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and included this file in the CDCat.xsl file.and added the tags - `<smallText>`, `<LineBreak>` in the CdCatalog.xml file. now when I open the xml file i dont see the LineBreak nor the font size difference. Can anyone please suggest if I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance
Sai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use apply-templates to indicate where your template matches should take effect.

Answer (score 0):

XML says nothing about presentation, that's the whole point. It's a *data* format.

If you want your XSLT to output to something where presentation matters I suggest you transform to HTML and get let HTML/CSS handle the styling.

---

Having seen your actual code now (hint: use the formatting when creating questions) don't use the font tag. What you want semantically and in practice is just headers `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>` etc, and I'd still suggest you add a CSS link in there. Oh and `<xsl:output method="html" />`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will surely keep them in them in mind!

Answer (score 0):

In-between these two opening tags:

```
<html>
<body>
```

...I'd place a link to a style sheet that defines the font sizes. Alternatively (and useful if you want a self contained HTML file to email around) you could put a style block there instead.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I actually have css stylesheet already defined, But my goal was make a part of the line from XML file to small font, and the rest to be as defined in css. so I added another xsl file.